# 12.04 screen resolution keeps changing after reboot

Tags: 12.04, resolution

running ubuntu 12.04 64-bit desktop on intel pentium 2 pc with 2gb of ram, ati hd3870 radeon, sony wega 50inch lcd tv.  I had no problems with any previous versions!

first, when i go to displays it shows as a laptop screen (not sony, like it did previously).

my main problem though is, i have to set the resolution to 1152 x 648 (16:9) to be able to see everything on the screen.  every time i reboot the pc when the desktop comes back up it resets the resolution to 1920 x 1080 (16:9) and i have to go in to the displays and reset it to the 1152 x 648.  and the next reboot, start it all over again, just a pain in the you know what!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for now until someone comes up with a better solution you could set the command:

`xrandr -s 1152x648`

to run as a startup application.

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: @iamanigeeit the basis for this answer was that you could set a command to run that would change the screen resolution automatically when you booted up the OS so if you can find a command that is working to change the resolution you should be able to substitute that commons for the one in my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry -- i was messing around with graphics drivers etc. As a workaround, it works if you put it last in the startup apps after everything else has run. You could also edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to specify Monitor PreferredMode but my laptop always went back to native resolution. In the end i accepted the native resolution and changed my font and icon sizes instead.